# Eclipse fails to compile pasted code

Tags: java, eclipse

This may be a stupid mistake of some sort on my part, but I'm walking through a Java GUI tutorial. When I copy and paste code from the tutorial into Eclipse, it finds an error in the pasted code. Trying to run it anyways yields console errors and an empty GUI window.

For example:

```
Checkbox chk15to20 = new Checkbox(“15 to 19 years old”, true, age);
```

Eclipse yields an error on the argument string, saying "Syntax Errors, ArgumentList expected instead" and "years cannot be resolved to a type."

I can fix the problem by manually re-typing, character by character, the code, at which point it compiles correctly.

Here's the error log when it's run (class is called Buttons):

> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       Syntax error on tokens, ArgumentList expected instead
>       years cannot be resolved to a type
>       Duplicate field Buttons.old
>       Syntax error on tokens, ArgumentList expected instead
>       Duplicate field Buttons.old

```
at practice1.Buttons.<init>(Buttons.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: my guess would be the quotation marks are not what they appear to be.

Comment: What if you were to try: `Checkbox chk15to20 = new Checkbox("", true, 1);`? Also - I noticed that the quotation marks used are somewhat funny. It could be that it's using a strange set of quotes (somewhere higher up in the ascii table) instead of just "".

Comment: The topic is kind of funny... ;)

Comment: request.setAttribute("reg", msg); it's working for me,just type this line manually in your IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your double-quotes are wrong. You need to use normal double-quotes, i.e. press SHIFT and ' on a US keyboard.

Like this:

```
Checkbox chk15to20 = new Checkbox("15 to 19 years old", true, age);
```

Comment: Stupid mistake it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have stylized quotation marks in the first argument. Try replacing them by hand.

```
Checkbox chk15to20 = new Checkbox("15 to 19 years old", true, age);
```